# Can I force an older version of TypeScript on a fresh dev PC build?

Tags: typescript

I've built a new dev PC. It has the latest Visual Studio and all that comes with it but my team are behind and there's a breaking change in TypeScript. The team won't update until we've shipped a certain release, just.. uff, don't even..

I need to install TS 1.7 and force it to use that. On GitHub there's the source code in ZIPs for older versions but... is that of much use? Can I compile that into something and install it or put it somewhere and point something at it?

Nightmare.

Luke

Comment: Can't you just specify typescript 1.7 in your npm dependencies in the package.json?

Comment: I'm not sure. I get a compiler error when VS builds the solution, I don't think npm is involved. We have grunt and npm for building the front end when we want to deploy but its called manually, or by our CI server. VS doesn't invoke npm, its not MVC vNext (ASP.NET Core whatever).

Comment: You could make a package.json, then specify the typescript version and then use `npm install` from the command line. Then you can run `tsc` and it will compile with your given version.